# Cannot connect to icecast2 server with BUTT as source

Tags: debian, icecast

I've setup an icecast2 server on a VPS, it's fully configured with a SSL certificate and is running on port 8000. I can see it listening with netstat, access the web interface from my laptop. But I can't connect to the server through BUTT for broadcasting (connect as a source). The issue is I don't have any log or error message on both end (in BUTT/my laptop or on the remote server log).

Do you have an idea how I could troubleshoot icecast's streaming source connection or any direct solution to the issue I'm encountering ?

Thank you

- Tried changing port, password, url (using domain name or IP)

Comment: maybe not what you want to hear, but fix your logs. Icecast has its `error.log`. Any error messages from BUTT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using BUTT because it can stream via SSL (which Audio Hijack can not). It is working fine when it is running but it will not reconnect after a connection loss. This is an issue of icecast since it will not drop the dead SSL connection.

Reconnect is only possible after I "sudo service icecast2 restart".

I am told the there are newer versions of icecast (2.50-beta.3 od 2.40-kh) that have resolved that issue.

This may not help you, but try connecting after a fresh restart of icecast. If it is still not connection your issues may be the SSL certs or port settings.